# automatically add transparent on resize overflow

Tags: c#, graphics

So I have this code to crop images

```
    private static Image Crop(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
        var part = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        return part;
    }
```

However, `cropArea` is occasionally out of bounds in the image, sometimes the crop extends outside the image and I want to fill these with transparent color, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Graphics` object against the destination image and draw the original image at translated point.

```
private static Image Crop(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
    //Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
    //var part = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
    //return part;

    Bitmap part = new Bitmap(cropArea.Width, cropArea.Height, img.PixelFormat);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(part))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(img, -cropArea.X, -cropArea.Y);
    }
    return part;
}
```